# Typescript macro sustitución?

Tags: typescript, ionic4

Tengo una aplicación Ionic 4 y en el archivo ts del componente, un if.

Quiero hacer la siguiente evaluación:

```
let pepe = "this.images[i].Name_barrio == 'Barrio 1'";
for (let i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
   if (pepe) {
       ...........
   }
```

Es posible que en el if se evalúe según la string y no sobre si pepe existe o no ? Pregunto esto ya que son varias condiciones que previamente construyen strings con diferentes cantidades de evaluaciones, según otras condiciones previas.

Cómo se puede hacer, de ser posible ?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hay formas de hacer que funcione, pero yo desaconsejaría usarlas. ¿Qué escenario tienes que necesite hacer algo así? No se me ocurre y uso Angular a diario...

Comment: Gracias Pablo por responder, tengo 4 select que pueden o no elegir una opción para filtrar una lista (si no elijo ninguna, es porque cualquiera es válida), luego, a partir de esos valores elegidos, quiero armar una string que sea la que se "evalúe" en el ngIf. No quiero trabajar sobre un vector recorriendolo, viendo las opciones, etc. Agradezco me orientes sobre qué usar

Comment: Tu condición, tal y como está escrita, va a recorrer el array `this.images` quieras o no, no entiendo por qué intentas evitarlo